# CSS backdrop filter too slow

Tags: css, filter, blur

Is there a way to be able to actually use this filter in production?

Because it's way too slow, and I have a new computer. This filter makes CPU spikes and makes the rendering of other animations not smooth

I am using it to create a blurred background effect with modal windows

Comment: Hi man, maybe you could include some code and or some examples...

Comment: There are some hacks you can use to somewhat increase performance (like using `translate3d` to create a rendering layer), but other than helping browser vendors actually optimize implementations, all you can do is wait it out until this relatively new technology is better optimized. Getting backdrop filters like this to work fast is a rather challenging task, and it'll take time for browsers to catch up.

Comment: Additionally, if you are using a non-translucent dialog and you only want the background blurred, you can work around the issue by just blurring everything outside the dialog, which should provide the same visual effect, with an improved performance.

Answer (score 1):

Yes I'm facing the same problem, I guess it's not a good practice to use backdrop blur property because of laggy ui. Just use a png image with blur effect on it (should be transparent) to overcome this problem. This was the only best solution i came up with.

```
background-image: url('your blur transparent image here'),linear-gradient(rgba(255,255,255,0.2),rgba(255,255,255,0.2));
background-size: cover;
```